# Powershell in VS2019 "Post-build" script causes NullReferenceException

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2019

I have a Powershell script for one of my VS2019 projects with the line

```
Remove-Item C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\foo\bar
```

The script is called in the "Post-build event command line" setting in the solution build. When this line is hit, it simply fails with:

```
Remove-Item : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
1>  At C:\Users\me\source\repos\Foo\Resources\Install.ps1:17 char:1
1>  + Remove-Item C:\Users\zachd\AppData\Roaming\foo\bar
1>  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1>      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-Item], NullReferenceException
1>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
1>   
1>  Remove-Item : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Running the exact same command line in a normal Windows Powershell instance works without issue, so I can only assume that this is caused by VS, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
Remove-Item -Path C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\foo\bar
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this out using force, recurse to remove and also to get more info add debug

```
Remove-Item -Path "location to the file/folder" -Recurse -Force -Debug

Remove-Item -Path "location to the file" -Force -Debug
```

In general if trying it from any script , permissions might be needed. So using force should resolve such issues for *Remove-Item*.